# $\tau > \sigma$ is a stoppinig time when $\sigma$ is a stopping time and $\tau$ measurable regarding $\mathcal{F}_\sigma$

Tags: stopping-times

The problem is depicted in the title. I want to know to complete my proof.

For any $t\ge0$ we want to show $$\{\omega;\tau(\omega)\ge t\}\in\mathcal{F}_t$$
Since we have $\tau\ge\sigma$. The left hand side could be split into two disjoint part depending on $\sigma$ that
$$\{\omega;\tau(\omega)\ge t\}=\{\omega;\sigma(\omega)\ge t\}\cup\{\omega;\tau(\omega)\ge t>\sigma(\omega)\ge0\}$$ 
Now $\{\omega;\sigma(\omega)\ge t\}\in \mathcal{F}_t$ since $\sigma$ is a stopping time. I think the second part is also in $\mathcal{F}_t $ from the fact that $\tau$ is $\mathcal{F}_\sigma$ measurable, but I can't get my mind clear on this.

Comment: You want the union of those two sets

Comment: Yes the union, sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer the question myself. I think this is the correct way of thinking:

By the definition of $\mathcal{F}_\sigma$ that 
$$\mathcal{F}_\sigma=\{F\in\mathcal{F}_\infty;\forall t\in\mathbb{R}_+,F\cap[\sigma\le t]\in\mathcal{F}_t\}$$
If $\tau$ is mesurable regarding $\mathcal{F}_\sigma$, we have $[\tau\ge t]\in\mathcal{F}_\sigma$, so $[\tau\ge t]\cap[\sigma\le t]\in\mathcal{F}_t$, which is what we want